# Programmatically distinguishing incoming calls between my custom call app or default android phone app

Tags: android, gsm

I'm trying to create an android call app. This app will be installed on both devices involved in a phone call. I need a feature werein my call app on the receiving device will be able to recognize wether an incoming call was made with my call app or with the default Android phone app. If possible, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is no space for "custom payload" carried by mobile call... but if there is any option fell free to correct me! :)

you probably should use another (de facto separated but synced) signaling transport, e.g. internet and some requestes/push msgs or just SMS with proper read permissions for apps (maybe [SMS Retriever API](https://betterprogramming.pub/android-automatic-sms-verification-with-googles-sms-retriever-api-c3dd580d543e) would be sufficient)